# cakephp change layout for different users

Tags: cakephp, layout

I'm newbie in cakephp, nevertheless I've searched for answers everywhere, especially cookbook.

I'm trying to make frontend and backend of my "tutorial blog" from tutorial of cakebook. I made different layouts in (`/View/Layouts`) named `admin.ctp`, `author.ctp` , `default.ctp`, and with a little code in controllers I could make a bet it's gonna works, but no.

```
    public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    if (isset($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'admin')
    {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }
    else if(isset ($this->params['prefix']) && $this->params['prefix'] == 'author')
    {
        $this->layout = 'author';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->layout = 'default';
    }

}
```

It's always choosing last default.ctp, and I don't know why

Comment: probably your prefixes are not recognized by cake and so it falls in the `else` statement. Could you update the question with the parts where you define the prefixes?

Answer (score 0):

(Answered in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> It turns that I hadn't set any prefixes in my `core.php`, I was trying to set them but without any progress, if someone may help me set some prefixes according to my code I will be grateful.
>
> Nevertheless I solved my problem editing my controller and it works fine. It's not professional, I know but for now it should works for me.

```
<?php

class ProductsController extends AppController
{
public $helpers= array('Html','Form','Session');
public  $components = array('Session');


public  function index()
{
    if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role') == 'admin')
    {
        $this->layout = 'admin';
    }
    else if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role') == 'author')
    {
        $this->layout = 'author';
    }
    else
    {
        $this->layout = 'default';
    }
    $this->set('item',  $this->Product->find('all'));
}?>
```